# Feynman rules for a $0$-dimensional field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, partition-function

Consider the partition function $Z(\lambda)$ of the $0$-dimensional scalar $\phi^{4}$ theory

$$Z(\lambda)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}d\phi\ \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\phi^{2}-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^{4}\right).$$

It can be shown that

$$Z(\lambda)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}\lambda^{n},$$

where $$c_{n}=\frac{(-1)^{n}(2n-1)!!}{(4!)^{n}n!}.$$

Can we instead propose a set of Feynman rules to compute the $c_n$'s, or can Feynman rules only be written down for the correlation functions of the theory?

Comment: Feynman rules are used to calculate correlations. The partition function is usually divergent and unobservable: it corresponds to the vacuum energy correction, which is only observed in specific nonfundamental cases, like the experiment measuring the Casimir force. But in this case it happens to be finite. Btw I have taken your sum in Methematica and it gave $Z(\lambda) = \sqrt{\frac{12}{12+\lambda}}$.

Comment: If the partition function is divergent, why can we extract the finite-valued correlators from the divergent partition function? Also, why does the partition function correspond to the vacuum energy correction?

Comment: What is there to stop us? The definition of the correlation contains an $n$-th order derivative of the generating functional in the numerator, and the partition function (which is equal to the generating functional evaluated at $j=0$) in the denominator. The divergences cancel each other to give a finite result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This partition function is divergent - the Taylor expansion has a zero radius of convergence. Also, could you explain why the partition function corresponds to the vacuum energy correction?

Comment: because you can always renormalize the vacuum energy by adding a constant energy counterterm. This counterterm corresponds to a coefficient in front of the partition function.